# Search Tool only refreshes Page without showing results

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, search, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a search tool that allows you to search plants based on multiple different taxonomies (Color, soil type, type, ect.) Each plant is set up as a post using ACF. You can search for plants based on the multiple taxonomies it has and the search tool was working fine until I added the get_field into the single.php file so that the information on the plant would be displayed once clicked on. Now every time you hit the search button the page only refreshes without narrowing down the results based on what is being searched, although the url will show that a search was made. Any ideas on what might be the issue?

Here is the code on the search tool page

```
<h2>Plant Selector</h2>
Use this tool to help choose the best native plants for your particular situation. Choose as many of the criteria as you want from the fields below and the plants matching your needs will be chosen from the total list.<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span>
<h3>Criteria</h3>
<form action="http://blue-thumb.org/plants/" method="get">
<div id="purpose" class="column first">

<label>Purpose</label>

<select name="purpose">
<option selected="selected" value="">Any</option>
</select>

<select name="purpose">
<option value="ng">Native Garden</option>
</select>

<select name="purpose">
<option value="rg">Raingarden</option>
</select>

<select name="purpose">
<option value="ss">Shoreline Stabilization</option>
</select>

</div>
<!-- .column -->
<div id="type" class="column">

<label>Type</label>

<select name="type">
<option selected="selected" value="">Any</option>
</select>

<select name="type">
<option value="grass">Grass</option>
</select>

<select name="type">
<option value="flower">Flower</option>
</select>

<select name="type">
<option value="tree">Tree/Shrub</option>
</select>

</div>
<!-- .column -->
<div id="bloom" class="column"><label>Bloom</label>
<strong>Color:</strong><select name="color">
<option selected="selected" value="">Any</option>
</select><select name="color">
<option value="red">Red</option>
</select><select name="color">
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select><select name="color">
<option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

<select name="color">
<option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<select name="color">
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<select name="color">
<option value="purple">Purple</option>
</select>

<select name="color">
<option value="white">White</option>
</select>

<select name="color">
<option value="pink">Pink</option>
</select>

<select name="color">
<option value="none">None</option>
</select>
<strong>When:</strong>

<select name="bloom">
<option selected="selected" value="">Any</option>
</select>

<select name="bloom">
<option value="4">April</option>
</select>

<select name="bloom">
<option value="5">May</option>
</select>

<select name="bloom">
<option value="6">June</option>
</select>

<select name="bloom">
<option value="7">July</option>
</select>

<select name="bloom">
<option value="8">August</option>
</select>

<select name="bloom">
<option value="9">September</option>
</select>

<select name="bloom">
<option value="10">October</option>
</select>

</div>
<!-- .column -->
<div id="care" class="column">

<strong>Level Of Care</strong>

<select name="level_of_care">
<option selected="selected" value="">Any</option>
</select><select name="level_of_care">
<option value="l">Low</option>
</select>

<select name="level_of_care">
<option value="m">Medium</option>
</select>

<select name="level_of_care">
<option value="h">High</option>
</select>

</div>
<!-- .column -->
<div id="environment" class="column first"><label>Environment</label>
<strong>Soil Moisture:</strong>
<label id="up" class="sub"><input name="moisture_up" type="checkbox" value="1" />Dry</label>
<label id="trans" class="sub"><input name="moisture_trans" type="checkbox" value="1" />Medium</label>
<label id="wet" class="sub"><input name="moisture_wet" type="checkbox" value="1" />Wet</label>
<label id="aquatic" class="sub"><input name="moisture_aquatic" type="checkbox" value="1" />Lake Plant</label><strong>Sun Exposure:</strong>
<label id="sun" class="sub"><input name="exposure_sun" type="checkbox" value="1" />Sun</label>
<label id="part" class="sub"><input name="exposure_part" type="checkbox" value="1" />Partial</label>
<label id="shade" class="sub"><input name="exposure_shade" type="checkbox" value="1" />Shade</label></div>
<!-- .column first -->

<input type="submit" /><span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span><a href="http://www.blue-thumb.org/plants/">Show All Plants</a>

</form>
```

Here is the code on the single.php file

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


    <?php get_template_part('includes/top_info'); ?>

    <div id="left-area">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if (get_option('modest_integration_single_top') <> '' && get_option('modest_integrate_singletop_enable') == 'on') echo(get_option('modest_integration_single_top')); ?>

        <div class="entry clearfix post">
            <?php
                $thumb = '';
                $width = 188;
                $height = 188;
                $classtext = 'post-thumb';
                $titletext = get_the_title();
                $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext,false,'Entry');
                $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
            ?>

            <?php if($thumb <> '' && get_option('modest_thumbnails') == 'on') { ?>
                <div class="post-thumbnail">
                    <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
                    <span class="post-overlay"></span>
                </div>  <!-- end .post-thumbnail -->
            <?php } ?>

            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.esc_html__('Pages','Modest').':</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link(esc_html__('Edit this page','Modest')); ?>
        </div> <!-- end .entry -->

        <?php if (get_option('modest_integration_single_bottom') <> '' && get_option('modest_integrate_singlebottom_enable') == 'on') echo(get_option('modest_integration_single_bottom')); ?>

        <?php if (get_option('modest_468_enable') == 'on') { ?>
            <?php if(get_option('modest_468_adsense') <> '') echo(get_option('modest_468_adsense'));
            else { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_option('modest_468_url')); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('modest_468_image')); ?>" alt="468 ad" class="foursixeight" /></a>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (get_option('modest_show_postcomments') == 'on') comments_template('', true); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>  <!-- end #left-area -->
<?php if (in_category('grants')) : ?>
            <?php the_field('address'); ?><br>
            <?php the_field('address_2'); ?><br>
            <a href="<?php the_field('url'); ?>"><?php the_field('url'); ?></a><br>
            <?php the_field('contact'); ?>
            <?php the_field('faq'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (in_category('plants')) : ?>

            <img src="<?php the_field('picture'); ?>" /><br>
            <b>Common Name: </b><?php the_field('name'); ?><br>
            <b>Scientific Name: </b><?php the_field('scientific_name'); ?><br>
            <b>Appropriate for: </b><?php the_field('appropriate_for'); ?><br>
            <b>Height: </b><?php the_field('height'); ?><br>
            <b>Type of plant: </b><?php the_field('type_of_plant'); ?><br>
            <b>Color of bloom: </b><?php the_field('color_of_bloom'); ?><br>
            <b>Blooms from: </b><?php the_field('blooms_from'); ?><br>
            <b>Sun Exposure: </b><?php the_field('sun_exposure'); ?><br>
            <b>Soil Moisture: </b><?php the_field('soil_moisture'); ?><br>
                        <b>Native To: </b><?php the_field('native_state'); ?><br>
            <a href="<?php the_field('usda_information'); ?>">USDA Information</a><br>
            <b>Notes: </b><br>
            <i><?php the_field('notes'); ?></i>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any ideas?

If it helps, here is the link to the page I am referring to.

http://www.blue-thumb.org/plants/

Comment: Submitting the form probably won't actually filter things automagically. Are you doing anything wit the `$_GET` values yet? Maybe look into [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) which will allow you to use the `$_GET` values to filter the main query ( or any query really ).